# How to replace dollar character with backslash dollar in a string

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I have a String like this:

```
String str = "aLnx5$bK$#C4EFg";
```

And I want to replace all the dollar `$` characters with backslash dollar `\$`, in order to get:

```
String expectedString = "aLnx5\$bK\$#C4EFg";
```

Comment: Have you even read the String javadoc?

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "aLnx5$bK$#C4EFg";
str = str.replace("$", "\\$");
```

Comment: I wouldn't reuse str, assign to a new string for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

try [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) function that replace any sequence character :

```
    String str = "aLnx5$bK$#C4EFg";
    String newStr = str.replace("$","\\$");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write this to replace the $ with \$

```
string newstring = str.replace("$", "\\$");
```

for more info see this [java doc: string.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Comment: That won't work as a single backslash is used as an escape character. To escape that use a double backslash.